# Redirect all traffic to temporary domain with 307 redirection

Tags: redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect the traffic to my temporary adress. Im using httaccess file to do that. That's the content of it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old.domain$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://new.domain/$1 [R=307, L]
```

It works if I enter adress: http://old.domain but it won't work with http://old.domain/somenting. It sends then 500 error. If I change R=307 to R=301 it works but I need 307 redirection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those rules work fine for me, but there's a syntax error in your rewrite rule's flags. You can't have a space after the comma:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old.domain$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://new.domain/$1 [R=307,L]
# no space here-------------------------------^
```

Comment: With R=301 it used to work with space. Strange. But thanks for that :)

Answer (score 0):

## You can try this:

```
   RewriteEngine on 
   RewriteCond   %{HTTP_HOST} old\.domain [NC]
   RewriteRule   ^/(.*)$      http://new.domain/$1 [R=307,L]
```

Comment: @Christina, try to put some explanation with your code, to make it more understandable.